# ORMLite auto-mapping of results to entity in custom query

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to perform complex query with joins - seems to be too complex to use `QueryBuilder`, so I'll SQL my way around. I know however, that result of this query will be a list containing only a single entity type. Is there a way to leave mapping of results to ORMLite? Usually I parsed results myself, but in this case entity contains a lot of fields and I really don't want to go into parsing those from `List<String[]>`...

Answer (score 0):

> ... that result of this query will be a list containing only a single entity type. Is there a way to leave mapping of results to ORMLite?

There certainly is.  If you take a look at the ["raw query" section of the documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries), you can see that it talks about the use of the [`RawRowMapper` class](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/RawRowMapper.html).  To quote from the docs:

> You can also map the results into your own object by passing in a `RawRowMapper` object. This will call the mapping object with an array of strings and allow it to convert the strings into an object. The DAO provides a default `RawRowMapper` that can be gotten from `orderDao.getRawRowMapper()` that knows how to convert the string array into the object.

So for this you would call [`dao.queryRaw(...)` with the `RawRowMapper` arg](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#queryRaw-java.lang.String-com.j256.ormlite.dao.RawRowMapper-java.lang.String...-) which maps from an array of strings.  There are other `dao.queryRaw(...)` methods including:

- [queryRaw(String, DatabaseResultsMapper, String...)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#queryRaw-java.lang.String-com.j256.ormlite.dao.DatabaseResultsMapper-java.lang.String...-) which allows you to map an object directly from the database results.
- [queryRaw(String, DataType[], RawRowObjectMapper, String...)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#queryRaw-java.lang.String-com.j256.ormlite.field.DataType:A-com.j256.ormlite.dao.RawRowObjectMapper-java.lang.String...-) which maps from an array of objects if you specify the result types.